Why a double cone is not a $3$-dimension manifold
I am trying to understand why a double cone is not a manifold.
A double cone refers to 2 cones in $R^3$ joined at the vertex. Formally, it is given by
$$ ={(,,)\in R^3:^2=^2+^2} $$
I have looked at other posts (Why is a double cone not a manifold?) and I understand why it can not be a $2$- dimension manifold.
However, I do not understand why it can not be a $3$-dimension manifold.
It seems to satisfy the two required conditions for manifolds:
1)It is a topological space
2)locally it resembles itself (which is a subset in $R^3$, hence is it homeomorphic to euclidean space)
Apologies for a somewhat trivial question, I can not seem to find any answers for this.

What do you mean by "double cone"?

"Locally it resembles itself" is a condition which has nothing to do with the definition of a manifold. For instance, the Cantor set is self-similar but is not a manifold.

"I have looked at other posts ... ." Which ones? What did they tell you so that you understand why the double cone is not a two-dimensional manifold?

A double cone refers to two cones who's vertex are joined together.
As for local resemblance, the second condition of a manifold is that it is homeomorphic to euclidean space. Here, is it not the case that it is homeomorphic to a subset in $R^3$ which is Euclidean?

Here is a related post I looked at :
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3784488/why-is-a-double-cone-not-a-manifold

The information that the previous comments asked for should be provided in the question. You can edit the question to make this so. I suspect that the answer to your question will be that the double cone is not an open subset of $\mathbb R^3$.

I believe I got it.
In $R^2$ we argued by contradiction that after removing the vertex, our cones are disconnected while the euclidean space remains connected.
Similar argument works for $R^3$.
I had the misconception that the ball around vertex is open.
Thank you!
